How can I view events of my downloaded application?
I want to know if this is possible - I have downloaded an Android app on my mobile, I want to know how and which "meta events" have been generated form this app. I don't have a source code nor apk file and I don't want to do anything which is not legal.
I tried google but no helpful contnet displayed as most of the results included sdk integration which required source code
PS - I'm more of a Camping advise and not a coder so might want to explain in layman terms (If in case someone finds an actual helpful answer)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
